# My APN function is able to send notifications from my Node.js app but callback is showing no reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, apple-push-notifications

How can I get a callback from my API function, so that I can forward it to my APIs?
I am just a newbie to JavaScript when I am using `callback()`. It is 
showing `callback()` is not a function.

```
function sendiosNotification(notification,callback){

    if(!notification.data.to){
        return callback({error : false, message : "receiver's deviceid is not available. could not send notificaion"});
    }
    var client = new apns.Provider({
        cert:"./cert/cert.pem",
        key:"./cert/key.pem",
        production: true,

    });
    var notifi = new apns.Notification();
    notifi.topic = "---"
    notifi.alert = notification.data.message;
    notifi.title = notification.data.username;
    device_token = notification.data.to;     
    client.send(notifi,device_token).then(result =>{
        console.log(result);
        callback()
    });
}
```

`data` is coming from my API. I can successfully send notifications to my devices but the function is not sending any response back.

Using `sendios` function in my API.

```
sendiosNotification({ data : data })
```

How to use response or callback to send the notification response back to API?

Comment: How are you passing in callback to the sendiosNotification function?

Comment: Passon callback in response. this is just code i have if u can help me

Answer (score 1):

this should work-

```
sendiosNotification({ data : data }, function(){
      console.log('callback called');
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

how callback function works

```
function i(num,cb){console.log(num), cb()};

i(1,function(){console.log("finish")})
```

**output:**

```
1
finish
```